# Installation using WUBI stops after reboot

Tags: 12.04, 13.10, system-installation

I am trying to install ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64 using wubi. I assigned 13gb and filled up everything required in the wubi installer. After rebooting the system I get the following error:

Try (hdd0,0) NTFS5: error "prefix" not set

and the says completing installation. But the installation stops. Only the background image is seen and nothing happens. Even the hdd blinking light stops blinking.

I even tried to go to safe mode and demo mode through grub but nothing happened.

Comment: Wubi is no longer officially support so I recommend you do a normal install.

Comment: Ohh... What is the normal style?? Can you please give me any link or something from where I could learn normal installation? I have windows7 already installed and I would like to make it a dual boot system.

Comment: Here is a link for dual booting, please read it carefully if covers more then one way to install ubuntu. < http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/installing >

Comment: Thanks for the help... But I would like to ask you that do I need to make a new partition to install ubuntu before I run the live CD to use the option "Install alongside windows 7" and next thing I would like to ask you that is there any chance of data loss?

Comment: Yes, you should run defrag on your windows partition, then use windows desk manager to shrink your windows partitions so you can create a new empty partition for ubuntu, then put in the livecd.

Yes there is a chance of data loss if you over write your windows partition so be very careful when working with partitions.

Comment: There is always a chance of data loss. **Make two backups in separate external media before trying anything.** As @WildMan says, shrink the Windows partition to make room for Ubuntu but leave the space unformatted/unallocated. Ubuntu will create its own partitions during installation. If your computer already has 4 primary partitions, you will have to **backup** and delete one you don't need.

Comment: I recommend using software like [Mini Tool Partition Manager](http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html) instead of the Windows Disk utility.

Answer (score 0):

WUBI is very unstable. You can test ubuntu with livecd/liveusb. When you use in install option "Install alongside Windows" you do not have a chance to lose data.

Comment: Do I need to create a new partition before I run livecd/liveusb ??

Comment: LiveCD is running system from cd/dvd disk. LiveUSB uses usb drive to test system from usb not cd or disk. When you testing with live session you not need install this system on disk. On windows can you use tools like universalusbinstaller for liveusb